# Calculate a month later than current month (without rolling over to next month)

Tags: php, datetime

I needed a script for working out billing dates over a period of time.  The date should be the same day every month however if the billing date starts on a date that doesn't exist in another month, then it should be on the last day of that month. This rules out the `DateTimeInterval` Object, because that causes months to 'rollover' (31/01 becomes 03/03 etc.) which is unacceptable for my use case.

Try as I might, I couldn't find anything in-built to accommodate for this, so I wrote the following, however it seems like a lot of code for what I'm trying to achieve so I was wondering if anyone could suggest a better / in-built way?

```
$replaceVars = array(
    'effectivedate' => '30-9-2014',
    'vatpc'         => 0.15,
    'paymentamount' => 150.00,
    'duration'      => 12
);

$effectivedateObj = new DateTime($replaceVars['effectivedate']);

$iD = array(
    'd' => $effectivedateObj->format('d'),
    'm' => $effectivedateObj->format('m'),
    'y' => $effectivedateObj->format('Y')
);

$payments = '';

for ($i=0; $i < $replaceVars['duration']; $i++) 
{
    $newDate = array(
        'd' => $iD['d'],
        'm' => (($iD['m'] + $i) > 12) ? (($iD['m'] + $i) % 12) : $iD['m'] + $i,
        'y' => (($iD['m'] + $i) > 12 ? $iD['y'] + 1 : $iD['y'])
    );

    if($newDate['d'] > cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $newDate['m'], $newDate['y']))
    {
        $newDate['d'] = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $newDate['m'], $newDate['y']);
    }

    $paymentString = '<tr>';

    $paymentString .= '<td>Payment Number '.($i+1).'</td>';
    $paymentString .= '<td>'. $newDate['d'] .'/'. $newDate['m'] .'/'. $newDate['y'] .'</td>';
    $paymentString .= '<td>&pound;'. round(( $replaceVars['paymentamount'] + ( $replaceVars['paymentamount'] * $replaceVars['vatpc'] )), 2) .'</td>';

    $paymentString .= '</tr>';

    $payments .= $paymentString;

    echo $paymentString . '<br>';
}
```

The top array and the lines that build the string are just for testing, but it still seems like a lot of code?

Also I have no idea how necessary my parenthesis are when creating ternary statements, and I do feel a bit neurotic about the amount that I use, so some advice on that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10):

I'm inclined to keep it simple:

```
$start = new DateTime('30-Jan-2014', new DateTimeZone("America/Toronto"));
$end = clone $start;
$end->modify('+1 month');
while (($start->format('m')+1)%12 != $end->format('m')%12) {
    $end->modify('-1 day');
}
echo $end->format('d-M-Y');
```

This just checks to see if the month is the expected one, and if not, backs up one day at a time until it is.  The advantage is that it's short, clear, and will work even in leap years (try 2004 to verify that).

**Edit:** It's also easy to make this into a user-defined function:

```
function addMonth($begin) 
{
    $end = clone $begin;
    $end->modify('+1 month');
    while (($begin->format('m')+1)%12 != $end->format('m')%12) {
        $end->modify('-1 day');
    }
    return $end;
}
```

Comment: would this work if the payment date were to span over two different years, from september 2013 - march 2014 for example?

Comment: Great solution, thanks for keeping it simple! Doesn't work in November though, since (11+1)%12 = 0. You can fix it by doing %12 on $end as well.

Comment: FYI, anon user posted this alternative solution in a suggested edit: http://smobilesoft.com/?p=265 (feel free to mark this obsolete on reception)

Answer (score 5):

I think the best thing you could do (as in easiest, most reliable and least code) is to go back to the `DatePeriod` class. Yes, it doesn't correct itself in terms of *"month-overflow"* (yet), but that's an easy fix:

Assume the data from your example:

```
$replaceVars = array(
    'effectivedate' => '30-9-2014',
    'vatpc'         => 0.15,
    'paymentamount' => 150.00,
    'duration'      => 12
);
```

Now let's see what we can do with this:

```
function getPaymentDates(array $data)
{
    $begin = new DateTime($data['effectivedate']);
    $period = new DatePeriod(
        $begin,
        new DateInterval('P1M'),
        (int) $data['duration'] //added cast to be sure, in case this data comes from DB
    );
    $clean = array();//<-- return this
    $last = (int) $begin->format('m');
    foreach ($period as $date)
    {
        while($last != $date->format('m'))
            $date->modify('-1 day');//subtract days until we get to the last day of the previous month...
        $clean[] = $date;
        if (++$last > 12)
            $last = 1;//no 13th month, of course...
    }
    return $clean;
}
```

I've tried this with starting date `2014-01-31`, and it produced the exact outcome you'd expect, no problem:

```
2014-01-31 00:00:00
2014-02-28 00:00:00
2014-03-31 00:00:00
2014-04-30 00:00:00
2014-05-31 00:00:00
2014-06-30 00:00:00
2014-07-31 00:00:00
2014-08-31 00:00:00
2014-09-30 00:00:00
2014-10-31 00:00:00
2014-11-30 00:00:00
2014-12-31 00:00:00
2015-01-31 00:00:00
```

But there is a problem here, of course: The period is 12 months in total, but this function returns 13 dates.
I did this for a reason, of course. There are 2 paths to go down for you, either pass a fourth argument to the `DatePeriod` constructor (`DatePeriod::EXCLUDE_START_DATE`), which will exclude the starting date from the returned dates, or return a slice of the array:

```
return array_slice(
    $clean,
    0,
    $data['duration']//in this case 12
);
```

Which drops the last date from the return array.
Ideally, I'd have this function take a second argument, with 3 possible values. Say, for example 1, 2 and 3: If that second argument is 1, then the first date won't be returned (basically, you'll pass `DatePeriod::EXCLUDE_START_DATE` to the constructor), if 2 is passed, then you'll slice the returned array (excluding the last date in the generated period). Passing 3 means that you return the resulting array (`$clean`) as is, no dates are removed, and its length will be that of `$data['duration']` + 1.

If this function will be used as a class method, then I'd suggest using constants for this.
In that case, your code could end up like this:

```
class Foo
{
    const EXCLUDE_EFFECTIVE_DATE = 1;
    const EXCLUDE_FINAL_DATE = 2;
    const EXCLUDE_NO_DATE = 3;

    public function getPaymentDates(array $data, $exclude = self::EXCLUDE_NO_DATE)
    {
        $begin = new DateTime($data['effectivedate']);
        $exArg = null;
        if ($exclude === self::EXCLUDE_EFFECTIVE_DATE)
            $exArg = DatePeriod::EXCLUDE_START_DATE;
        $period = new DatePeriod(
            $begin,
            new DateInterval('P1M'),
            (int) $data['duration'],
            $exArg
        );
        $clean = array();
        $last = (int) $begin->format('m');
        foreach ($period as $date)
        {
            while($last != $date->format('m'))
                $date->modify('-1 day');
            $clean[] = $date;
            if (++$last > 12)
                $last = 1;
        }
        if ($exclude === self::EXCLUDE_FINAL_DATE)
            return array_slice($clean, 0, $data['duration']);
        return $clean;
    }
```

To generate the same output as you are getting now, becomes a piece of cake, and doesn't require ugly code (computation mixed in with `echo`'s isn't nice...):

```
$foo = new Foo;//<-- class-like example
$replaceVars = array();//<-- imagine your data here
$dates = getPaymentDates($replaceVars, Foo::EXCLUDE_FINAL_DATE); //is what you're doing now
//assuming you have echo '<table><tbody>'; here somewhere
//Calculate the payment values up front please!!
$payment = round($replaceVars['paymentamount'] + $replaceVars['paymentamount'] * $replaceVars['vatpc'], 2);
foreach ($dates as $i => $date)
{
    echo '<tr><td>Payment number: ', $i+1, '</td><td>',
         $date->format('d/m/Y'), '</td><td>',
         '&pound;', $payment ,'</td></tr>';
}
echo '</tbody></table>';
```

So one thing: calculate the payment value once, and echo it in the loop. There is *no point* in calculating the same thing over and over, just assign it to a temp variable and use that instead.
As an asside: yes, those are *comma's* I'm using in the `echo` statement, and not concatenating `.` (dot)-operators. `echo` is a language construct that works in a similar fashion to C++'s `std::COUT`. You can push any number of values to it, it'll just push them to the `stdin` sequentially. That way, there's no reason to allocate new memory, and copy string chars to create a new, big string constant that'll just be passed to echo anyway.

I've already [explained this in great detail here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20596098/php-closing-tag-deletes-the-line-feed/20596645#20596645), in the comments below my answer there, there's a link to a page where the differences in exec. time are mentioned, too. Bottom line: The difference isn't dramatic, but `echo` without concatenation is faster.

Answer (score 5):

In the past I have run in to this problem.

My PHP is non-existent, but the problem can be broken down and simplified....

1. only 5 months of the year are vulnerable to this problem (in all other months, the following month has more or the same number of days):

   - January
   - March
   - May
   - August
   - October
2. in the months with problems, you only have to worry about anything when the day-of-month is >= 29 (for January) or the 31st for other months.
3. for days >= 29 in January the answer is (1 day less than march 1st)

So, in reality, there are only (about - depending on leap years) 7 days in the year where this is a problem.

For those 6 days 4 of them are constants (march 31, May 31, Aug 31 and Oct 31), and the January one needs some help.....

So, a cascading *if* statement should work fine, and be fast.... using some artistic license with PHP syntax, it would look like:

```
if (dayofmonth == 31 || (month == january && day > 28))
{
    billdate->add('P1M'); // add a month, it will overflow to following month
    dom = .... // get the day-of-month of the new billdate
    billdate->sub('P' + dom + 'D'); // subtract the nw day-of-month (will be 1 for most months, but may be as much as 3 for the 3rd of March....)....
}
else
{
    billdate ->add('P1M');
}
```