# Too many nested blocks fixed but not sure if this way is right

Tags: php, beginner, html, datetime

I have previeous;y posted my php code with way to many nested blocks I hope I fixed it right.

I'd also like some tips on my OOP, as this is new to me.

```
class event {

//Builds the event in html
    public function renderEvent($Array) {
        echo "</p>";
        echo "<p>";
        if ($Array['ad']) {
            echo "<img src='images/" . $Array['ad'] . "' alt='event-ad' width='300' height='100' />";
        } else {
            echo "&nbsp;";
        }
        echo "</p>";
        echo "<p>&nbsp;</p>";
        echo "<div class='toggleLink' style='cursor: pointer; color: #333;'>";
        echo $Array['starttime'] . "  " . $Array['title'];
        echo "</p>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo " <div class='toggle'>";
        echo "<p class='toggleLink'>";
        echo "(" . $Array['starttime'] . "-" . $Array['endtime'] . ") " . $Array['location'] . " - " . $Array['address'] . " - Admission Price: $" . $Array['price'] . "<br>" . $Array['description'];
        echo "</div>";
    }

    public function recurring($recur, $event, $Date, $savedDate) {
        $recurring = $recur['type'];
        $displaydate = $Date->format("Ymd");
        $startdate = date('Ymd', strtotime($recur['startdate']));
        $enddate = date('Ymd', strtotime($recur['enddate']));
        Switch ($recurring) {
            Case 'None':
                //If the date in the range is the same as the displaydate
                if ($Date->format("Ymd") == $savedDate->format('Ymd')) {
                    //Create event
                    $this->renderEvent($event);
                }
                break;
            Case 'Daily':
                //Check margin between start and end date of recurring event
                $this->check_date_range($displaydate, $startdate, $enddate);
                $this->recur_daily($recur, $event, $Date);

                break;
            Case 'Weekly':
                //Check margin between start and end date of recurring event
                $this->check_date_range($displaydate, $startdate, $enddate);
                $this->recur_weekly($recur, $event, $Date);

                break;

            Case 'Monthly1':
                //Check margin between start and end date of recurring event
                $this->check_date_range($displaydate, $startdate, $enddate);
                $this->recur_Monthly1($recur, $event, $Date);
                break;
            Case 'Monthly2':
                //Check margin between start and end date of recurring event
                $this->check_date_range($displaydate, $startdate, $enddate);

                //Code still to be made.

                break;
        }
    }

    public function check_date_range($displaydate, $startdate, $enddate) {
        //Check margin between start and end date of recurring event
        if (!($displaydate >= $startdate) && !($displaydate <= $enddate)) {
            exit();
        }
    }

    public function recur_daily($recur, $event, $Date) {
        //Check if the day number is the same
        if ($recur['day'] - 1 == $Date->format("w")) {
            //Create event
            $this->renderEvent($event);
        }
    }

    public function recur_weekly($recur, $event, $Date) {
        $first = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $recur['startdate']);
        $second = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $recur['enddate']);
        if ($recur['enddate'] > $recur['startdate']) {

        }
        $weekRange = floor($first->diff($second)->days / 7);
        $weeks = $weekRange / $recur['weekday'];
        //Returns the week cuurent week to display
        $currentWeek = $Date->format("W");
        //Loop for every #(1, 2, 3, 4) of weeks
        for ($n = 0; $n < $weeks; $n++) {
            //Display event if weeks are the same
            if ($n == $currentWeek) {
                //Put days in array
                $days = explode(",", $recur['weekday']);
                //If number day of the week is the same display event
                foreach ($days as $day) {
                    //Check if the day number is the same
                    if ($day == $Date->format("w")) {
                        //Create event
                        $this->renderEvent($event);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public function recur_Monthly1($recur, $event, $Date) {
        //make string to date
        $bdate = strtotime($recur['startdate']);
        $edate = strtotime($recur['enddate']);

        $monthsRange = 0;

        //get how many month are between two dates
        while ($bdate < $edate) {
            $monthsRange++;
            $bdate = strtotime('+1 MONTH', $bdate);
            if ($bdate > $edate) {
                $monthsRange--;
            }
        }

        $months = $monthsRange / $recur['month'];

        //Do for (selected number up to 4) every month
        for ($n = 0; $n < $months; $n++) {

            //Check to see if it is the same day in the month
            if ($recur['day'] == $Date->format('d')) {

                //Create event
                $this->renderEvent($event);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

//Display event with renderEvent
    public function dispalyEvent(DateTime $Date) {
        $event_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM calendar WHERE Approved='Approved' ORDER BY starttime");
        //Go through all event in the database
        while ($event = mysql_fetch_array($event_query)) {
            $date1 = new DateTime($event['startyear'] . $event['startmonth'] . $event['startdate']);
            $date2 = new DateTime($event['endyear'] . $event['endmonth'] . $event['enddate']);
            $date2->modify('+1 day');
            $period = new DatePeriod($date1, new DateInterval('P1D'), $date2);
            $title = $event['title'];
            $name = $event['name'];
            $recur_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM recur WHERE title = '$title' AND name = '$name'");
            $recur = mysql_fetch_array($recur_query);

            //Go through each date in the range
            foreach ($period as $savedDate) {
                $this->recurring($recur, $event, $Date, $savedDate);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please state the goal of your class so that we can help you refactor it.

Comment: well I want to display events and depending if they are recurring it could display multiple times on different dates in the calendar. My goal is to make my code as efficient as possible and eliminate DRY (don't repeat yourself). And also to see if I used the proper way to program as I am a beginner.

Answer (score 4):

Given that this is a follow-up question, and [I've dealt with some issues here already](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/45801/i-have-a-huge-function-filled-with-nested-blocks), I'm not going to be as verbose. I will, however, refer to a couple of my initial critiques, and offer some advice on this code, too. I see several issues, I've listed them below, but some do require some explanation, so if after a huge blob of text, you see a new list item, that means I'm touching on a new subject. Just for clarity, because this answer could do with some refactoring, too :)

- ***Functions return***: Functions, or methods for that matter, ***do not `echo` anything***. Functional entities (functions, methods, and classes, for that matter) *return* things, they do not `echo`. The `renderEvent` method you have is still littered with `echo` statements.
- ***Classes throw, they don't exit***: A class is a single, supposedly portable unit. It should not be able to control the entire flow of the application it is a part of. That's why methods contain no `exit` calls, your do. ***DON'T. DO. THAT!***. When a method encounters an issue, and the class has no code to deal with such an event, then you have an *"exceptional"* situation. What any good class then does is *throw an exception*. For example:

Say I have this method:

```
public function notGreatButJustAnExample(array $argument)
{
    $return = '';//instead of echo
    if (isset($argument['images']) && is_array($argument['images']))
    {
        foreach ($argument['images'] as $k => $image)
        {
            $return .= ($k+1).' image == '. $image. PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
    if (!isset($argument['important_key']))
    {//without this, I can't continue
        throw new InvalidArgumentException(__METHOD__.' needs important_key to be set in argument-array');
    }
}
```

I need this key, without it, the method can't do its job. If that key is missing, the data is, too, and the method has received an invalid argument. Hence, the `InvalidArgumentException` is thrown.
Other exceptions that could be thrown in such a method is when 2 keys need to be arrays that are equally long, for example `$argument['images']` and `$argument['img_descriptions']`. If the two arrays exist, but aren't equally long, then the code that called the method probably contained bad logic, in that case:

```
if (count($argument['images']) != count($argument['img_descriptions']))
{
    throw new LogicException('Number of images does not match number of descriptions');
}
```

Notifies the user of this problem. Think of exceptions as your class shouting back at whomever calls one of its methods: *"If you want me to do so and so, then I expect valid input. If I don't have valid input, then that's your problem"*. That's why you throw it back to the caller.

- ***only make `public` what needs to be called***: What the user doesn't need, he shouldn't see. Any method that is used *internally* by the class, shouldn't be callable from anywhere else. The user should *not* be allowed to call it, so make it `protected` (or `private`). I tend to prefer `protected`, which means that, if every you extend your class, the children will have access to these methods, too. `private` methods only exist in the scope of the class itself. `protected` exists in the scope of the class, and all of its children.
- ***Style and standards***: Try to adhere to [the coding standards](http://www.php-fig.org) as much as possible. That is to say: class names start with an Upper-case char, and their opening brace go on the next line. You wrote `class event {`.

According to the standards (unofficial, but it's the only one we've got), it should be written like this:

```
class Event
{
```

- ***A S.O.L.I.D. start***: The SOLID principles are well known by many. I'm prepared to defend the following statement(s) to the bitter end, though I am aware that this might enrage some people. The most important of all [SOLID principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) is, IMHO, SRP. The *Single Responsability Prinsiple*. These principles aren't just for show. A lot of *good practices* and principles sound great in theory, but the SOLID principles tend to be quite easy to follow, especially the SRP. Not only are they easy to apply, they will in fact help you write better, more generic code quite easily.
  I've always been skeptical about *"ultimate mega-super-unbeatable-design theories"*, believe you me. But these 5 principles are just simple, common-sense ideas put together. What is wrong with common sense?

If you answered nothing to my rhetorical question, you should realize 2 things: First, you don't answer to rhetorical questions and second:  Your class violates the SRP quite blatantly. It connects to the DB and fetches data (1 task/reason to change), formats it (another task/reason to change) *and* takes care of the output (another task/reason to change). That's 3 distinct responsibilities. Ideally, you'd use 3 classes for this, but given PHP's suitability as a templating language, 2 will do, too (the output part can be a simple PHP+HTML script, containing *no logic* other than the occasional loop and `if-else`.

- ***"What's in a name?"***: *That, which you call `event`, by any other name would work as good*... Or something. Well, when writing code, there's a lot in a name, especially when classes are involved.

Allow me to explain myself:
Good code is *self-documenting*. A class name, and its methods tell the user a lot about what it's for. Your class is called `Event`. If I see a line of code that reads `new Event()`, I expect it to create a data model, an instance that describes an *event* of sorts.
Once I notice I can pass it instances of `DateTime`, I'll assume the instance describes an event that can be recurrent, or stretch out over a period of time. I'd also expect to be able to pass strings (descriptors) and perhaps an array of attendees to this object.

This data itself should be gotten via an `EventMapper` instance, which does the DB work. At least, I'd expect to see something of the sorts. This mapper could have methods that return `Event` instances, depending on arguments (for example: 2 dates, returns an array of all events that take place in that date range).

These `Event` instances could then move on to an `EventRenderer` class, which has a `getOutput` or `render` method. The constuctor could take a value (preferably predefined constants) that set the output mode I'd like. When I call this `render` method, I'd expect it to ***return*** something that I can echo, if I so desire. I might choose to write the output to a file or DB, too. That's up to me, not up to the class to decide. Hence: *method's don't echo*. Here's an example:

```
class RenderEvent
{
    const RENDER_JSON_MODE = 1;
    const RENDER_HTML_MODE = 2;
    const RENDER_XML_MODE = 4;
    const RENDER_ALL_MODES = 7;

    protected $mode = null;

    public function __construct($mode = self::RENDER_HTML_MODE)
    {//default
        $this->mode = $mode;
    }

    /**
     * Takes an event, renders it according to the set mode
     * @param Event $event
     * @return string
     */
    public function render(Event $event)
    {
        if ($this->mode === self::RENDER_ALL_MODES)
        {//return assoc array, use constants as key
            return array(
                self::RENDER_JSON_MODE => $this->setOutputMode(self::RENDER_JSON_MODE)
                        ->render($event),
                self::RENDER_HTML_MODE => $this->setOutputMode(self::RENDER_HTML_MODE)
                        ->render($event),
                self::RENDER_XML_MODE => $this->setOutputMode(self::RENDER_XML_MODE)
                        ->render($event),
            );
        }
        if ($this->mode === self::RENDER_JSON_MODE)
            return $event->toArray();//or something
        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        if ($this->mode === self::RENDER_HTML_MODE)
        {
            $dom = new DOMDocument;
            $table = $dom->createElement('table');
            //build dom
            return $dom->saveHTML();
        }
        //no if required, we're rendering XML once we get here
        //very similar to render HTML, but:
        return $dom->saveXML();
    }

    /**
     * Change output mode
     * @param int $mode
     * @return EventRenderer
     * @throws InvalidArgumentException
     */
    public function setOutputMode($mode)
    {
        if ($mode === self::RENDER_ALL_MODES)
            $this->mode = $mode;
        else if (($mode & self::RENDER_ALL_MODES) === $mode)
            $this->mode = $mode;
        else
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('Use constants for modes, '.$mode.' is not a valid output mode');
        return $this;
    }

}
```

This code allows the user to use your events in ajax calls, or NoSQL data storage situations:

```
$event = new Event();//<-- assume everything is set up
$renderer = new EventRenderer(EventRenderer::RENDER_JSON_MODE);
$json = $renderer->render($event);
$mongo->save($json);
//or in AJAX call context:
echo $json;
```

As you can tell, I have the choice here: echo or pass the rendered data. That makes this code a more likely candidate for re-use.

- ***type-hints***: You've used 1 type-hint. That's all fine and dandy, but I'd like to see you use type-hints as much as possible. The first method takes one argument `$Array`, but what if I were to pass a string? change the signature to `public function renderEvent(array $Array)`, to prevent such issues.
- ***Markup is structured, strigs are not***: stringing together markup is un-maintainable. As you start getting the hang of OOP, you'll perhaps one day want to `extend` this class. Having it string together markup will mean you'll have to override any method that does so, in order for it to work in the child's context. That's not ideal.
  Add to that the fact that stringing together markup is a delicate procedure, and once a bug rears its ugly head, it's a nightmare to debug.
  Using a `DOMDocument` instance allows you to create nodes, hold references to them, and add, remove and move them about in the dom as you please. Ensuring valid markup every time. Chec [the documentation for `DOMDocument` and all its related classes](http://www.php.net/DOMDocument). It's a bit tricky to get your head round at first, but it *is* worth it.

---

Now, `mysql_*`. You've commented on my other answer, saying you are aware of `mysql_*` being deprecated, but the project is already using this extension. Pardon my french, but that's utter bulls***.
If the existing code is using a *deprecated* an (hopefully) soon to be removed extension, the *last* thing you should be doing is adding new code that makes that very same mistake. You'll have to refactor the existing code at some point in the future. By adding more code that will need to be refactored, the only thing you're doing is increasing the amount of code that will need to be re-written.

Do I mean that you should refactor the entire project before you start adding code? Not necessarily. But if you are going to add new features/code, then at least write them in such a way that *the new code* doesn't require refactoring! That's common sense.

I always like to use extensive analogies to explain what I'm saying, so humour me and let me give you a weird analogy for this, too:
Say you have a house, it's not brand new, but it's home. There are a couple of doors that squeek and the carpets could do with some cleaning. Due to circumstances, you've had to spend your savings on an annexe you're building. Would you fit that annexe with dirty, old, worn out carpets, or would you fit new, nicer carpets there first? Of course you'd go for the new carpets, and you'd start saving up to fit new carpets in the rest of the house as soon as possible.
What you're doing is the exact opposite. You're writing new code (ie building an annexe), but you're fitting it with the same old, worn out and scruffy carpets. That kind of takes the shine away, doesn't it? And to add insult to injury, you'll have to save up some more, because when you want to refit the carpet, you'll have to buy more, and there's going to be more work that needs doing, too. Save yourself the pain of having to do twice the work: whatever code you add, make sure it's future-proof. Meanwhile, work on ditching that `mysql_*` from the existing code-base.

You can do this quite easily now that you've decided to go with an OO approach. The great thing about your using classes is that a class needn't care about anything that is going on outside of itself. It can hold its own DB connection (not create it itself, but rather _inject it as a dependency => SOLID), using whatever extension *you* (as its author) choose. I'd suggest you provide your class with an up-to-date db connection, and think about refactoring the rest of the project in due time.
Whatever you do ***do not increase the amount of code you'll need to refactor*** by simply adding `mysql_*` code. Whatever new code code you add should use the new extensions. The old code should be re-factored, or factored out.

**Some other niggles**
The code you have now still suffers from the same injection vulnerabilities I pointed out in my initial answer. Other issues still exist, too, like your creating new `DateTime` instances too many times. The `recur*` methods, too, could do with a bit more work.
As luck would have it, I've [written a substantial answer that is very much related to what you're doing](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/46047/calculate-a-month-later-than-current-month-without-rolling-over-to-next-month/46049#46049) just yesterday. Check that out, and refactor the recurrency methods accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explain your code better. Give an example of some input and output. What does the value of `$Date` represent and how does it relate to the purpose of diplsayEvent()? Define a daily, weekly, monthly1, and monthly2 reoccurring event. What is the format and meaning of `$recur['weekday'] $recur['day'] $recur['month'] $event['startdate'] $event['enddate'] $event['startyear'] $event['startmonth']`? This information is important to evaluate if your code works as intended and how it can be improved. I had to make some assumptions below. My suggestions are in the comments. I changed the style of the code just because it is easier for me to read. There is nothing wrong with your style it is neat and consistent. You should continue using your style.

```
class Event
{
  public function dispalyEvent(DateTime $Date)
  {
    // I'm not sure of the format of startdate and enddate, but this optimization might be possible.
    // SELECT * FROM calendar WHERE Approved='Approved' AND startdate <= $Date AND $Date <= enddate ORDER BY starttime"
    // This MySQL extension is deprecated switch to a supported extension.
    // If you call this function with multiple $Dates then run this query once, cache it, and pass the results to this function.
    $event_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM calendar WHERE Approved='Approved' ORDER BY starttime");
    // Check return value.
    if($event_query == false)
      return;

    // You don't use numbered indices so exclude them.
    while($event = mysql_fetch_array($event_query,MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
      // Move date logic together.
      $title = $event['title'];
      $name = $event['name'];

      // 1. Warning: SQL Injection Vulnerability
      //    Any user that may alter $title or $name may change your query.
      //    mysql_query() normally only allows one statement per call, but do not depend on that for security. It also doesn't prevent selecting other tables.
      // 2. Select based on unique IDs not things like title and name, which might not be unique.
      // 3. There seems to be a one-to-one mapping between rows in calendar and rows in recur, with title and name being duplicated. Add the columns of recur to calendar to reduce the number of queries.
      //    Post your database design to http://dba.stackexchange.com/ for more suggestions on how to improve your database.
      $recur_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM recur WHERE title = '$title' AND name = '$name'");
      // Check return value.
      if($event_query == false)
        continue;
      $recur = mysql_fetch_array($recur_query);
      if($recur == false)
        continue;

      // Now let's simplify your date logic.

      // Again, I'm not sure of the format of startdate and enddate. You might have to convert these to a DateTime using a different method.
      $startdate = new DateTime($recur['startdate']);
      $enddate = new DateTime($recur['enddate']);

      // Move this check to the top.
      if( ($startdate > $Date) || ($Date > $enddate) )
        continue;

      // This code will call renderEvent() once for every valid reoccurring date, but the output of renderEvent() is the same every time.
      // I'm guessing that you only want to call renderEvent() once if $Date is a reoccurring date for the event.

      // $date1 = new DateTime($event['startyear'] . $event['startmonth'] . $event['startdate']);
      // $date2 = new DateTime($event['endyear'] . $event['endmonth'] . $event['enddate']);
      // $date2->modify('+1 day');
      // $period = new DatePeriod($date1, new DateInterval('P1D'), $date2);
      // Go through each date in the range
      // foreach ($period as $savedDate)
      //   this->recurring($recur, $event, $Date, $savedDate);

      switch($recur['type'])
      {
        case 'None':
          $this->renderEvent($event);
          break;
        case 'Daily':
          $this->recur_daily($recur, $event, $Date);
          break;
        case 'Weekly':
          $this->recur_weekly($recur, $event, $Date);
          break;
        case 'Monthly1':
          $this->recur_Monthly1($recur, $event, $Date);
          break;
        case 'Monthly2':
          //Code still to be made.
          break;
      }
    }
  }

  // We no longer use this method, but I'm guessing that you don't want to call exit(). That will prevent other events from being rendered. Return a value instead.
  // You would use it like
  // if(!$this->check_date_range($displaydate, $startdate, $enddate))
  //   $this->recur_daily($recur, $event, $Date);
  // private function check_date_range($displaydate, $startdate, $enddate)
  // {
  //   // Simplify boolean logic.
  //   return ($displaydate < $startdate) || ($displaydate > $enddate);
  // }

  // We don't want code outside this class to call this method so make it private.
  private function recur_daily($recur, $event, $Date)
  {
    // Check if day of weeks are the same.
    if($recur['day'] - 1 == $Date->format("w"))
      $this->renderEvent($event);
  }

  //private
  private function recur_weekly($recur, $event, $Date)
  {
    // Create array of reoccurring day of week.
    $days = explode(",",$recur['weekday']);
    // Check if the day of week of $Date is in the array of reoccurring days.
    // In recur_daily() the day of week was off by one, so consider if you need to do this.
    //if(in_array($Date->format("w")+1,$days))
    if(in_array($Date->format("w"),$days))
      $this->renderEvent($event);
  }

  //private
  private function recur_Monthly1($recur, $event, $Date)
  {
    //$Date must be on month $recur['month'] and day $recur['day'].
    if( ($Date->format("m") == $recur['month']) && ($recur['day'] == $Date->format('d') )
      $this->renderEvent($event);
  }

  //private
  private function renderEvent($Array)
  {
    // Warning: Not Secure.
    // Anyone that can modify ad, stattime, endtime, title, location, address, price, or description in your database can print anything they want to a visitor's browser.
    // This includes a cookie stealer, malware, or obscene pictures.
    // Users could also destroy your HTML by accident.
    // Consider if a user enters the following for a description: "<a Do stuff <b Do other stuff <c ??? <d Profit".
    // You must escape the output so it cannot print valid HTML, javascript, etc.
    // I will leave this for you to research and implement.

    // Check opening and closing of p tag.
    echo "</p>";                    // Open p tags: -1
    echo "<p>";                     // Open p tags: 0
    if($Array['ad'])
      echo "<img src='images/" . $Array['ad'] . "' alt='event-ad' width='300' height='100' />";
    else
      echo "&nbsp;";
    echo "</p>";                    // Open p tags: -1
    echo "<p>&nbsp;</p>";           // Open p tags: -1
    echo "<div class='toggleLink' style='cursor: pointer; color: #333;'>";
    echo $Array['starttime'] . "  " . $Array['title'];
    echo "</p>";                    // Open p tags: -2
    echo "</div>";
    echo " <div class='toggle'>";
    echo "<p class='toggleLink'>";  // Open p tags: -1
    echo "(" . $Array['starttime'] . "-" . $Array['endtime'] . ") " . $Array['location'] . " - " . $Array['address'] . " - Admission Price: $" . $Array['price'] . "<br>" . $Array['description'];
    echo "</div>";
  }
}
```

Comment: Completely disagree with your comment of leaving out type-hints. If a method is _public_, it can be called by anyone who creates an instance of this class. The clearer the API, and the more restrictive (within reasonable bounds) the methods' signature is,the better. Leave the type-hint out, and you could call this method with `displayEvent(array('Foo' => 'bar'));`, and your method would fail. _force_ the user to pass a _valid_ argument as much as you can.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me. That was my misunderstanding of the language.

Comment: Cheers, removed -1. Though perhaps edit your answer a bit more. ATM, you ask what the meaning of `$Date` is. The type-hint (`DateTime`) makes this quite clear: it's a `DateTime` instance, which can be used to create a formatted date string `($Date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')` yields that date as MySQL would format it, for example

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I suspect "what is the meaning of `$Date`" has more to do with the poorly-named variable  than it's type: the date of what? today? the event start? three full moons from now? Similarly, `$Array` should be `$event` or whatever data the array holds. *Never* name a variable based solely on its type.

Comment: @DavidHarkness: Hence my mentioning _"what's in a name"_ and self-documenting code in my answer. But instead of just asking a rhetorical question, if you review code, you should offer some suggestions or at least explain the issue you have with a var name, no? If not, your answer is as vague as the `$array` variable

Comment: @DavidHarkness: just say my comment. If you took it as being defensive or dismissive, that's not how I intended it :)

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem No worries. I misunderstood your initial comment ("the type-hint makes this quite clear") to mean the name `$Date` was appropriate which we both agree it is not. I hadn't read through your whole answer since it was an obvious +1 after the first few paragraphs. ;)